How is the partcile も used after a plain verb?
なんとか立たせるも、首が座っておらず、不気味な笑顔をうつむかせている。
The character caught an evil person. He is now forcing him to stead up and his narration communicates this. As I understand it, it's "Even if I make him stand up, he doesn't hold his head up and looks down with a creepy smile"
Does も here provide the same nuance as ても?

Semantically it's the same as ても or けれども but it sounds more literary.
See this dictionary entry.
